# Developing a CMS from scratch or using Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, content-management-system

I want to ask if it is better to develop a CMS from scratch, making a good CMS core framework, or should I develop my CMS with the Zend Framework. I have experience in working with Zend Framework, but feel like it will not have a good success because of the large library that Zend has.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not planning to use an existing CMS framework? This wheel has been invented so many times by this point that it seems a strange decision to be considering creating another one from scratch.

Comment: Create frameworks from scratch is a good learning practice. But generally a bad choice if you're planning to use it in your projects. It's indeed a bad practice to use Zend Framework in day-to-day jobs without knowing it sufficiently.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to answer what I think can objectively be answered.

ZF is a general purpose component library. It doesnt offer components related to the CMS problem domain, e.g. no documents, no workflows, versioning, etc. So even if you use ZF, you will have to implement the CMS specific parts, e.g. your domain model and all the business logic (your CMS core), from scratch.

ZF can solve some of the general problems of an application like authentication, caching, db access, stuff like that. So for those aspects, ZF might be useful for you. As for the size of the library: that is not an issue. You do not have to use components you do not need. Just pick those that are useful for you.

As an alternative to ZF check out [Apache Zeta components](https://incubator.apache.org/zetacomponents/documentation/trunk.html). It offers workflows and documents in addition to many components ZF offers as well - unfortunately, development on that has stalled lately.

Comment: I think there is one CMS framework based on Zend.

Comment: Was only an additional comment, Zend itself isn't a CMS, true.

Comment: @markus I gave up complaining about that ;)

Comment: Concret5 is a famous CMS build  with ZF :D search for it :D